# how can i get HttpContext.Current.Request of more than 1000 html controls value?

Tags: c#, html, httprequest, namevaluecollection

I have more than 1000 controls in a html web page. when i submit the page i get only values of 1000 controls

```
NameValueCollection nv = (NameValueCollection) HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

nv.count is 1000 , how can i get HttpContext.Current.Request of more than 1000 html controls value ?

Comment: and what is the question? Try asking a question in your question body

Comment: do all controls have runat="server" attribute?

Comment: No, all are html input controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver has a limit on how large requests it will allow.

If you are using IIS you can check out 
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

But i would suggest using some other technique to post your data, maybe AJAX

Answer (score 0):

What the - how can you sensibly have 1000+ input controls? Smells like "one page to rule them all". THAT is your problem. You wont get around that - likely the browser does not publish them. Your best bet i not to submit a webpage, but to use AJAX and construct some JSON payload with all the values.